# How to force gcc to link like g++?

Tags: gcc, g++

In this episode of "let's be stupid", we have the following problem: a C++ library has been wrapped with a layer of code that exports its functionality in a way that allows it to be called from C.  This results in a separate library that must be linked (along with the original C++ library and some object files specific to the program) into a C program to produce the desired result.

The tricky part is that this is being done in the context of a rigid build system that was built in-house and consists of literally dozens of include makefiles.  This system has a separate step for the linking of libraries and object files into the final executable but it insists on using gcc for this step instead of g++ because the program source files all have a .c extension, so the result is a profusion of undefined symbols.  If the command line is manually pasted at a prompt and g++ is substituted for gcc, then everything works fine.

There is a well-known (to this build system) make variable that allows flags to be passed to the linking step, and it would be nice if there were some incantation that could be added to this variable that would force gcc to act like g++ (since both are just driver programs).

I have spent quality time with the gcc documentation searching for something that would do this but haven't found anything that looks right, does anybody have suggestions?

Comment: Run g++ with the verbose flag and observe the arguments.

Comment: `gcc -lstdc++` and `g++` are actually different wrt. static objects.

Comment: @Steve-o: this is correct, but I'm not using statics in my code and tend to avoid them in general.  If I had been relying on static initialization in my C++ code, I would have used your idea of wrapping gcc in a script that would call g++ for the linking phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Many thanks to bmargulies for his comment on the original question.  By comparing the output of running the link line with both gcc and g++ using the -v option and doing a bit of experimenting, I was able to determine that "-lstdc++" was the magic ingredient to add to my linking flags (in the appropriate order relative to other libraries) in order to avoid the problem of undefined symbols.

For those of you who wish to play "let's be stupid" at home, I should note that I have avoided any use of static initialization in the C++ code (as is generally wise), so I wasn't forced to compile the translation unit containing the main() function with g++ as indicated in item 32.1 of FAQ-Lite (http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/mixing-c-and-cpp.html).

Answer (score 1):

Considering such a terrible build system write a wrapper around `gcc` that `exec`'s `gcc` or `g++` dependent upon the arguments.  Replace `/usr/bin/gcc` with this script, or modify your `PATH` to use this script in preference to the real binary.

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ "$1" == "wibble wobble" ]
then
  exec /usr/bin/gcc-4.5 $*
else
  exec /usr/bin/g++-4.5 $*
fi
```

Comment: This is a good idea, and probably what I will attempt if there is no easier solution, but I currently dread having to dig around in the build system to see if there is any variable that will allow me to change the compiler.

Comment: This should probably be `...-4.5 "$@"`, since `$*` will cause problems if there are spaces in the command line arguments (and since this is apparently a sprawling, in-house build system, that's rather likely).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that C linkage produces  object files with C name mangling, and that C++ linkage produces object files with C++ name mangling.

Your best bet is to use
    extern "C"
before declarations in your C++ builds, and no prefix on your C builds.

You can detect C++ using

```
#if __cplusplus
```

Comment: I already have the name mangling problem solved correctly, the undefined symbols are all related to support functionality required for the C++ part of the code to run correctly.

Comment: You can compile and link in separate steps. run gcc -c On the C stuff, g++ -c on the C++ stuff, then run link to link them together.

Comment: That is already being done, the problem is undefined symbols on the linking step.  I have managed to solve it now, see my accepted answer.